# Using OpenRefine to clean addresses - Cluster Exact Match

Tags: csv, cluster-analysis, openrefine, data-cleaning

I am using Open Refine to clean up some addresses in a sheet (.csv). How do I cluster exact match in a column? It seems that the clustering algorithm will cluster addresses that are almost similar which only differs in the number. For example:

```
56, LORONG RENGAS, SELANGOR
76, LORONG RENGAS, SELANGOR
90, LORONG RENGAS, SELANGOR
76, lorong rengas, selangor
56, LORONG RENGAS, SELANGOR
```

How do I use OpenRefine to cluster these addresses according to exact match? Question sounds silly but I'm losing my head over this thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using the facet function? Facet group records based on an extact match. You can watch [those video on faceting and data profiling](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8vPOPM1_9htE1PtYLy8Y36OsDk-6EF6s).

Comment: Thanks, I've watched the videos and after cracking my head for a while I finally managed to do so by adjusting the parameters when doing the clustering.

Comment: @Hack-R please try again. This should be fixed.